# How to restrict SharePoint permissions for below senerio?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions

We have a SharePoint integration with CRM.

CRM creates document libraries, folders and document from its system. Back-end is SharePoint.

From CRM system, users cannot access the files created by other users, but how ever users started accessing back end SharePoint site directly to access the files and folders created by other users.

In SharePoint the permissions are inherited from parent site, breaking inheritance is one option but that option could be very tedious as maintain permissions for 300 folders could be difficult.

Is there anyway we can restrict users from access the SharePoint site directly? Or is there any better solution for the above scenario?

Comment: Do your CRM system uses some kind of dedicated service accounts that creates/uploads all the stuff in your SharePoint? Or are the user interacting with SharePoint directly through your CRM?

Comment: User directly interactes with CRM. When I look at folder properties, I see folder created by username via CRM.